# How to copy one array to another in C programming

Tags: arrays, c

I was trying a program which is requesting me to copy odd elements of one array to another array.This is the best logic that i can develeop until now. But it doesn't work properly. Could you please find my mistake and help me to correct it. Thanks in advance :)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
  int array[10], oddArray[100], i, j = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("Element %d:", i + 1);
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 2 != 0) {
      oddArray[j] = array[i];
      j++;
    }
  }
  for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
    printf("%d\n", oddArray[j]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *But it doesn't work properly.*  That's not a good description of your problem.  What **does** it do?

Comment: array is size 10, oddarray is 100 - how any why? oddarray needs to be (#of element of the main array/2)+1, at most.

Comment: Your `oddArray[j]` at the bottom should be `oddArray[k]`.

Comment: Always declare each variable on its own line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Furkan, change the last loop's iterating variable in oddArray from j to k:

```
for(int k=0;k<j;k++) {
    
printf("%d\n",oddArray[k]);

}
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you little distraction took half an hour from me :/. Now it works all good. Thanks for rapid answer again :)